# Query with pre_get_posts to get pagination

Tags: wp-query, pagination, pre-get-posts

After pretty much getting everything working with `query_posts`, I noticed my pagination wasn't running. I was told `pre_get_posts` should be the solution.

My problems:

1. I don't know how to pass all my criteria
   `(query_posts(array('post_type' => 'trips', 'types' => $types,
   'paged' => $paged,)`in to `pre_get_posts`
2. I can't get it working on
       (just) the template I want, which is used on a page (`is_page`
       doesn't work)

   Any help would be appreciated.

This is what's inside functions.php

```
function bwpm_pre_get_posts($query){
    if(!$query->get('posts_page_page'))
    $query->set('posts_per_page',1);
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts','bwpm_pre_get_posts');
```

This is what's in the template that is used on the page.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Generic Trips Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( "beforeloop", "page" ) ?>
                                    <?php $types = $post->post_name; ?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php 
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        query_posts(array( 
            'post_type' => 'trips', 
            'types' => $types, 
            'paged' => $paged,
        ) );
    ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post"></article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div style="text-align:center;">
<?php posts_nav_link(' &#183; ', 'previous page', 'next page'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( "afterloop", "page" ) ?> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Update: 11/06/2012
After updating the code to @chipbennet example, the problem still isn't solved as I don't get properly working pagination. The previous link will never appear, and the next link will show the same content on every page. Full page code can be found on http://pastebin.com/NiuSEWia.

Comment: I'm using this on a page, so I've tried `is_page`, but that ain't working. I've also tried to get more criteria in to the `pre_get_posts`, but can't find a good example and that ain't working either. If anyone has a good example... .

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to **accomplish**? I get that you're trying to manipulate the pagination, but: **why**? What's the intended outcome? Knowing that will help answer the question.

Comment: @ChipBennett I was using `query_posts`, but didn't get pagination working. Now I'm trying to basically get everything working the way it was when I WAS using `query_posts`, and also get pagination working. Unfortunately, I don't know how to pass all my criteria in to `pre_get_posts`, nor do I seem to manage to get it working on the template I want it.

Comment: You're describing an **implementation method**, without explaining *what you're trying to implement*. **Why** do you need to manipulate pagination? What, **ultimately**, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't need to manipulate pagination. I'm trying to have my custom template, which is used on a page to function the way a normal posts page would work. The only reason I'm not using the normal way is because I need to a) add some criteria (post type, types), and b) I want to call it only on a certain page.

Comment: Okay, so: you're trying to create a *custom page template* that displays a *custom post type*? Let me know if that's accurate; I'll write up an answer accordingly.

Comment: @ChipBennett Yes, it should display a custom post type. Thought that was clear from the arguments passed to the query. Sorry if it wasn't. I already found a way to get this working on my MAIN category, but NOT on subcategories. Basically all I have to do is add the global variable `$page` instead of an actual number. This way, WordPress will get the actual pagenumber and add to the query. In short: `'paged' => $page,` provides me with a working solution.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you want to *create a **custom page template** to display a **custom post type***? If so, you don't really need to mess with `pre_get_posts` at all.

**First**, create your custom page template. I assume you've already done this.

**Second**, you need to *create a custom query*, using [**`WP_Query()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
global $post;
$types = $post->post_name;

$trips_query_args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'trips', 
    'types' => $types, 
);

$trips_query = new WP_Query( $trips_query_args );
```

(Note: what is the `'types'` parameter? As far as I know, it's not a core query parameter. Are you using it somehow?)

**Third**, we need to let WordPress know that it needs to base pagination on our *custom query* rather than on the *default query*:

```
global $wp_query;
// Put default query object in a temp variable
$tmp_query = $wp_query;
// Now wipe it out completely
$wp_query = null;
// Re-populate the global with our custom query
$wp_query = $trips_query;
```

At this point, we've moved the *default* query into a temporary variable, and re-populated the `$wp_query` global with our *custom* query.

**Fourth**, we need to output our custom query loop:

```
if ( $trips_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $trips_query->have_posts() ) : $trips_query->the_post();

    // Normal loop output goes here
    // You can use loop template tags normally
    // such as the_title() and the_content()

endwhile; endif;
```

Just put your loop output into the above. I've omitted it for brevity.

**Fifth**, we just need to reset things:

```
// Restore original query object
$wp_query = $tmp_query;
// Be kind; rewind
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This should be all you need to output a custom query loop, with proper pagination.

#### Edit

The use of taxonomy `{slug} => {term}` [as a query taxonomy parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) was deprecated in WordPress 3.1, in favor of `'tax_query'`. You should replace this:

```
'types' => $types
```

...with this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'types',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'term'     => $types
    ) 
)
```

This would make your `$types_query_args` array look like this:

```
$trips_query_args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'trips', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'types',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'term'     => $types
        ) 
    )
);
```

#### Edit

> @ChipBennett interesting development. I added 'paged' => N to the $trips_query_args array, where N stands for a number. When adding 1 the page actually shows exactly the perfect results for page 1. When adding 2 it shows the perfect results for page 2. However when using the navigation links OR even manipulating the URL, it no longer works. Any ideas?

So, let's try forcing the query pagination, using the following:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

You would update your `$trips_query_args` array accordingly:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$trips_query_args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'trips', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'types',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'term'     => $types
        ) 
    ),
    'paged'    => $paged;
);
```

Does that result in correct pagination?

Comment: +1: good explanation. @WouterB WordPress generates a page by: parsing the url as a query (applying `pre_get_posts`, retrieving the content from DB and then choosing a template. I.e. content is determined before templates. If you want to determine the content once the template has been retrieve you need to use this method.

Comment: That said - WP (can) support post type archives - so you might want to make use of that, tweaking it with `pre_get_posts` - possibly with the use of custom query variables

Comment: I *suspect* that the OP intends to use some page meta data to build the custom query, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @ChipBennett "types" is indeed a custom taxonomy. The page template is used on multiple categories. It calls only the posts that have the correct category.

Comment: @ChipBennett Using your example I now have exactly the same results on page 2 as I have on page 1. Hope you can take another look. I've added the pages complete code on pastebin. http://pastebin.com/NiuSEWia

Comment: Is `types` the slug for your custom taxonomy? Are you wanting to query for the *taxonomy* itself, or for a specific taxonomy *term*? How are you using a *static page template* on a *category*?

Comment: Can you remove the custom taxonomy bit, just for troubleshooting? It's not implemented properly, and I want to verify that it isn't interfering with anything. Also: can we see the code in the included template-part files, just for reference?

Comment: @ChipBennett ["Types" isn't the slug.](http://pastebin.com/LYTjKbeL) I'm querying for the taxonomy term (name), which is working fine by the way. I also tried removing just this code, but that didn't make a difference. Here's the two pieces you asked for: ["beforeloop"](http://pastebin.com/rgZ8ZQWj) and ["afterloop"](http://pastebin.com/e8uG9nK5).

Comment: How are you using a static page template on a category? The "types" taxonomy (= taxonomy term) is added as a "filter" and will only show posts for that taxonomy.

Comment: "*The "types" taxonomy (= taxonomy term) is added as a "filter" and will only show posts for that taxonomy.*" - Where is the code that performs this filter? **Also**: do you have a live link to a page demonstrating this behavior?

Comment: @ChipBennett
`$types = $post->post_name;

$trips_query_args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'trips', 
    'types' => $types, 
)` filters this, which is working. All the code sits on my dev server at the moment. If it would help I could zip all files for you though.

Comment: Using taxonomy slug as a query argument (e.g. for `WP_Query()`) was actually [deprecated as of WordPress 3.1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), in favor of `'tax_query'`. Would you like for me to add `'tax_query'` implementation into my answer?

Comment: @ChipBennett no thanks, I'm sure I can figure that out myself. It's just the pagination conundrum that's got me baffled.

Comment: I've added it anyway. Who knows; it might be causing a problem. If not: can you post a `var_dump()` of `$trips_query`, both on page 1 and on page 2?

Comment: @ChipBennett Adding `tax_query` broke the loop, displaying no posts. I've completely commented out the `types` part now, so it won't affect the pagination issue. [Here's the full page code again](http://pastebin.com/jmHyLibv), and here's the var dumps for [page 1](http://pastebin.com/U6asDhh2) and [page2](http://pastebin.com/pTXWpDf2).

Comment: @ChipBennett interesting development. I added `'paged' => N` to the `$trips_query_args` array, where `N` stands for a number. When adding `1` the page actually shows exactly the perfect results for page 1. When adding `2` it shows the perfect results for page 2. However when using the navigation links OR even manipulating the URL, it no longer works. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, outputting the `$page` global I can see that on the lower down pages `root/something/something/page/2` for some reason the global remains `1` even though the end of the URL says: `page/2`. It works fine on `root/page/2`

Comment: Let's try to force pagination. You shouldn't need to do this, but for some reason, the query's not picking it up. See updated answer.

Comment: Noppé, that doesn't work. I now temporarily worked around it so I can continue the development and launch isn't postponed by too long. The workaround is simple. I get the page number from the URL and add it. That works like a charm. Still want to find the root cause, but I'm starting to doubt I'll find it.

Comment: @ChipBennett I've never given a bounty before and I'm kind of uncertain as to what to do. I do appreciate your help and would say that you've by far helped me the most. The bottom line however is that I don't have a clean solution. What do you think is fair?

Comment: "*The workaround is simple. I get the page number from the URL and add it.*" - Can you post that code?

Comment: [Line 10 -> 25 is used to do this.](http://pastebin.com/sN6gAGA8)

Comment: There might be a simpler way to do that. :) What does the URL look like with pretty permalinks disabled?

Answer (score 3):

WordPress figures pagination details based on the *main query*, and before the template is parsed. Which is probably why somebody recommended that you leverage pre_get_posts.

I don't know what the "beforeloop" and "afterloop" template parts in your code are for, but it looks like you're trying to let the main (page) query stand for the page header, then switch to a custom query, then switch back to the main query with wp_reset_query(). This approach won't work if you expect pagination to function properly, and is not a recommended approach to multiple queries in general. If you want two queries on a page, one of them should be a custom query [using WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or something similar.

You can either:

- Determine if there's a natural WP equivalent of the page you're
  trying to create (for example, it look slike you're trying to create
  a post type archive, or a custom taxonomy term archive), and use this
  natural template instead. Check the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).
- Change the *entire* main query using pre_get_posts, and get anything else you need (the stuff currently in the beforeloop and afterloop) using a custom query. You can set all query params in pre_get_posts the same way you've set the posts_per_page param. For example:

  $query->set('posts_per_page',1);
  $query->set('post_type','trips');

Etc. You shouldn't need to manipulate the paged var if you're paginating based on the main query like this.

Comment: using what you describe results in a 404 page. `function bwpm_pre_get_posts($query){ if(!$query->get('posts_page_page')) $query->set('posts_per_page',1); $query->set('post_type','trips'); } add_action('pre_get_posts','bwpm_pre_get_posts'); `

Comment: @WouterB Sorry for the misunderstanding--I didn't mean to suggest that setting those two vars is all that's needed to get the result you want--I'm not *exactly* sure what that is. But that example is definitely how you set query params using pre_get_posts (in answer to your question #1). How to set query params and how to get exactly the result you're after are two different questions :) I still think your best bet is to figure out if there's a native query/template combo that fits your needs. As I said, it looks like a basic post type archive for a custom post type. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using pre_get_post. I found one implementation that works for me:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'ucc_add_cpts_to_pre_get_posts' ) ) {
    function ucc_add_cpts_to_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_post_type_archive() && ! is_singular() && ! is_404() ) {
            $my_post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
            if ( empty( $my_post_type ) ) {
                $query->set('post_type', 'your_custom_type');
                $query->set('posts_per_page', 'your_posts_per_page');
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ucc_add_cpts_to_pre_get_posts' );
```

http://uncommoncontent.com/2012/01/28/add-custom-post-types-to-the-loop
You must remove query_posts from your template.