# Pagination 404s on custom query

Tags: pagination, 404-error, blog

The basic issue is that every paginated page for my blog is going to a 404 page. /page/2/, /page/3/, etc. It used to be working fine, but is not now. I think maybe the change to 3.9 did it.

Here are some of the many things I have tried in an effort to fix this. The end result of all of these were the same. The paginated links 404'd.

- deactivated all plugins
- removed and reset permalinks multiple times
- tried permalinks as default rather than /postname
- Ensured my Reading Settings > Blog pages show at most was set to the same number as my loop. (as well as more and less to test)
- I tried two separate navigation plugins and the default wordpress pagination (older posts) and it 404s every time. 
  tried using parse_query
- tried paginate_links

Here is my code (or links to my code):

home.php

```
    <?php require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/blog-page.php';
```

blog-page.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog Page - Custom
*/

get_header(); ?>

<---CUSTOM CODE--->

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   $args = array(
       'posts_per_page' => 5,
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'paged' => $paged
   );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($wp_query->have_posts()) : 

   while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<---CUSTOM CODE--->


   endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();?>

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
<?php  endif; wp_reset_query();
```

If it helps, here is a [test site](http://hracuity.staging.wpengine.com/blog/) I've set up with the page in question. I've left it off with the default wordpress pagination.

I've run out of things to try. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I also tried this option here, but couldn't post the link tried this option here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54509/query-with-pre-get-posts-to-get-pagination

Comment: why are you creating a new query in your template and not using the default main query?

Comment: You are not going to have reliable pagination with overriding main query in template. Never. Seriously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things I don't understand here, but I'll try answering them as I go along.

You have a home.php, which I assume is your default homepage. You have one line of code in there, and that is to call a another page template. Here is you code

```
  <?php require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/blog-page.php';
```

In blog-page.php you have the complete page template. My question is, why are you doing this. Why not just add the content of blog-page.php into home.php? Would make more sense.

You are not using the main query to run your loop, but a custom one, which I also don't understand, as your custom query does exactly the same as the main query, except for posts per page. This whole custom query can be avoided by just using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to set a custom number of posts on your homepage.

```
function posts_on_homepage( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '5' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'posts_on_homepage' );
```

You can just add this into functions.php which will set your amount of posts on your homepage to 5, and then you can replace the custom query with a normal loop.

One thing to keep in mind here, whenever you run a custom query, pagination will fail as stated in the comments.

You will need to have a look at [`WP_Qeury`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)'s pagination parameters.

> **paged (int)** - number of page. Show the posts that would normally show up just on page X when using the "Older Entries" link.
>
> **page (int)** - number of page for a static front page. Show the posts that would normally show up just on page X of a Static Front Page.

So your query should look like this for normal pages

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

And like this for static pages

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

You are also resetting your postdata twice. You should only do that once. BTW `wp_reset_query();` is wrong, it is only used for `query_posts` that should not be used. You should be using `wp_reset_postdata();`

Lastly, when using a custom query, you have to specify the maximum namber of pages for [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) by using the `$max_pages` parameter, otherwise it will fail.

```
 next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
```

Here is an example of a proper working custom query as from the codex

```
<?php
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
   <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
?>

<?php 
// clean up after our query
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php else:  ?>
   <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this will shed some light on your problem

Comment: Thank you so very, very much for taking the time to write up such a detailed response. I've tried so many options, I think I was ending up with a mess. I am definitely saving what you wrote out as it will help me many times in the future. I copied my code from blog-page.php and moved it to home.php. I changed to just the default query. I then added that function to limit the number of posts. I had it set in Reading Settings, but the page was ignoring that even after moving to home.php. Any idea why that would be? Either way, it's working perfectly now. I can't thank you enough for your help.

Comment: Did you set a homepage in "Reading Settings >> Front page displays". If not, edit your question and add the code that is currently in home.php so I can quickly have a look at it :)

Comment: Yeah, I've got that set. See here: http://imgur.com/n8YINbI
Here is my new home.php http://pastebin.com/bTHRMFqT
If I remove the function you gave me, all posts display and there is no pagination. If I add the function, then the correct amount display and it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but none of the above helped me out. I was able to write a little workaround for this totally annoying situation.

1. Examine the URL
2. If /page/2 is present, write a redirect rule to add a query string to the url
3. Make use of that query in your paging.

---

```
//Set a URL segments Global (functions.php)
global $segments;
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$segments = array_filter($segments);
$segments['classes'] = implode(' ', $segments);
```

---

```
//Add this rewrite in your functions.php to add a query string to target
add_action( 'init', 'forum_paging_redirect', 10 );
function forum_paging_redirect( $redirect_url ) {
    global $segments;

    if($segments[1] === 'forum' && $segments[2] === 'page') {
        echo '<script>window.location = "/forum?topics_page='.$segments[3].'";</script>';
    }
}
```

---

```
// Instead of native pagination function, echo this puppy:
if(!empty($query_topics)) {
    $total = $query_topics->max_num_pages;
    $page = $_GET['topics_page'];

    for($i = 1; $i < $total +1; $i++) {
        if($i == $page) {
            echo '<span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">'.$i.'</span>';
        } else {
            echo '<a class="page-numbers" href="/forum/?topics_page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
        }
    }   
}
```